# Nature of firefly Luciferase reaction mechanism?

Tags: enzymes, bioluminescence

The bioluminescence of the firefly luceferin (FL) is a two step process, with the first step requiring the enzymatic/catalytic ability of the luciferase to convert the FL into  luciferyl adenylate.

Are there any descriptions for the mechanism in which the Luciferase facilitates the reaction of ATP with the firefly luciferin?

Comment: I answered a similar question of yours about aequorin, initially explaining how to go about finding the information and subsequently explaining in some detail aspects of the enzyme mechanism. Perhaps you didn't see my expanded answer, but until you respond to that (accepting it if it answers your question) I have no way of knowing whether that type of answer is what is required.  I described how to go about finding literature on enzyme mechanisms. What are the results of your efforts to do that in this case?